# Kubernetes API server not able to register master node

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, kubeadm, kubectl

I was trying to create a Kubernetes Cluster using kubeadm. I had spin up an Ubuntu 18.04 server, installed docker (made it sure that docker.service was running), installed kubeadm kubelet and kubectl.

The following are the steps that I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common -y
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` test"
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker-ce
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker

curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main"
sudo apt-get install kubeadm kubelet kubectl -y
sudo apt-mark hold kubeadm kubelet kubectl 
kubeadm version
swapoff –a
```

Also, in order to configure the Docker cgroup driver, I had edited **/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf**. Within the file, I added `Environment="KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd"` and commented out `Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"`.

**/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf** for reference:

```
# Note: This dropin only works with kubeadm and kubelet v1.11+
[Service]
Environment="KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS=--bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
#Environment="KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS=--config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
Environment="KUBELET_CGROUP_ARGS=--cgroup-driver=systemd"
# This is a file that "kubeadm init" and "kubeadm join" generates at runtime, populating the KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS variable dynamically
EnvironmentFile=-/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
# This is a file that the user can use for overrides of the kubelet args as a last resort. Preferably, the user should use
# the .NodeRegistration.KubeletExtraArgs object in the configuration files instead. KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS should be sourced from this file.
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/kubelet
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet $KUBELET_KUBECONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_CONFIG_ARGS $KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS
```

After this I ran: `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl restart kubelet`. kubelet.service was running fine.

Next, I ran `sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` and got the following error:

> root@ip-172-31-1-238:/home/ubuntu# kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
> [init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.23.1
> [preflight] Running pre-flight checks
> [preflight] Pulling images required for setting up a Kubernetes cluster
> [preflight] This might take a minute or two, depending on the speed of your internet connection
> [preflight] You can also perform this action in beforehand using 'kubeadm config images pull'
> [certs] Using certificateDir folder "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
> [certs] Generating "ca" certificate and key
> [certs] Generating "apiserver" certificate and key
> [certs] apiserver serving cert is signed for DNS names [ip-172-31-1-238 kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 172.31.1.238]
> [certs] Generating "apiserver-kubelet-client" certificate and key
> [certs] Generating "front-proxy-ca" certificate and key
> [certs] Generating "front-proxy-client" certificate and key
> [certs] Generating "etcd/ca" certificate and key
> [certs] Generating "etcd/server" certificate and key
> [certs] etcd/server serving cert is signed for DNS names [ip-172-31-1-238 localhost] and IPs [172.31.1.238 127.0.0.1 ::1]
> [certs] Generating "etcd/peer" certificate and key
> [certs] etcd/peer serving cert is signed for DNS names [ip-172-31-1-238 localhost] and IPs [172.31.1.238 127.0.0.1 ::1]
> [certs] Generating "etcd/healthcheck-client" certificate and key
> [certs] Generating "apiserver-etcd-client" certificate and key
> [certs] Generating "sa" key and public key
> [kubeconfig] Using kubeconfig folder "/etc/kubernetes"
> [kubeconfig] Writing "admin.conf" kubeconfig file
> [kubeconfig] Writing "kubelet.conf" kubeconfig file
> [kubeconfig] Writing "controller-manager.conf" kubeconfig file
> [kubeconfig] Writing "scheduler.conf" kubeconfig file
> [kubelet-start] Writing kubelet environment file with flags to file "/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env"
> [kubelet-start] Writing kubelet configuration to file "/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml"
> [kubelet-start] Starting the kubelet
> [control-plane] Using manifest folder "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
> [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-apiserver"
> [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-controller-manager"
> [control-plane] Creating static Pod manifest for "kube-scheduler"
> [etcd] Creating static Pod manifest for local etcd in "/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
> [wait-control-plane] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests". This can take up to 4m0s
> [kubelet-check] Initial timeout of 40s passed.
>
> ```
>     Unfortunately, an error has occurred:  
>             timed out waiting for the condition  
>
>     This error is likely caused by:  
>             - The kubelet is not running  
>             - The kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way (required cgroups disabled)  
>
>     If you are on a systemd-powered system, you can try to troubleshoot the error with the following commands:  
>             - 'systemctl status kubelet'  
>             - 'journalctl -xeu kubelet'  
>
>     Additionally, a control plane component may have crashed or exited when started by the container runtime.  
>     To troubleshoot, list all containers using your preferred container runtimes CLI.  
>
>     Here is one example how you may list all Kubernetes containers running in docker:  
>             - 'docker ps -a | grep kube | grep -v pause'  
>              Once you have found the failing container, you can inspect its logs with:  
>             - 'docker logs CONTAINERID'
> ```

After running `systemctl status kubelet.service`, seems that kubelet is running fine.
However, after running `journalctl -xeu kubelet`, I got the following logs:

> kubelet.go:2347] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized"
> kubelet.go:2422] "Error getting node" err="node "ip-172-31-1-238" not found"
> kubelet.go:2422] "Error getting node" err="node "ip-172-31-1-238" not found"
> controller.go:144] failed to ensure lease exists, will retry in 7s, error: Get "https://172.31.1.238:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/ip-172-31-1-238?timeout=10s": dial tcp 172.31.1.238:6443: connect: connection refused
> kubelet.go:2422] "Error getting node" err="node "ip-172-31-1-238" not found"
> kubelet.go:2422] "Error getting node" err="node "ip-172-31-1-238" not found"
> kubelet_node_status.go:70] "Attempting to register node" node="ip-172-31-1-238"
> kubelet_node_status.go:92] "Unable to register node with API server" err="Post "https://172.31.1.238:6443/api/v1/nodes": dial tcp 172.31.1.238:6443: connect: connection refused" node="ip-172-31-1-238"
> kubelet.go:2422] "Error getting node" err="node "ip-172-31-1-238" not found"

**Versions:**
**Docker:** Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed57
**Kubeadm:** {Major:"1", Minor:"23", GitVersion:"v1.23.1", GitCommit:"86ec240af8cbd1b60bcc4c03c20da9b98005b92e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-12-16T11:39:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.17.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Not sure whether this is a connection issue between the Kube Api Server and Kubelet.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kubeadm version used here is 1.23.1. Kubernetes doesn't provide direct support for docker anymore. [read here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/). In my understanding, you have both installed but they are not connected. Also I dont see you have containerd.io specified in the docker installation command. [Refer here.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository)

Option 1: Install contianerd. [Please follow this step.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#containerd)
If the problem still persists then, Configure kubelet service to use containerd by adding the following options in the kubelet service.

```
--container-runtime=remote --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock
```

Option 2: Install docker properly and configure as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#docker).

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful.

Comment: @arjunbnair if this answer has helped you, then I think you can mark this as accepted answer so that other users can be sure about this answer and context. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by going through the Kubernetes official documentation on creating a cluster using kubeadm. Following are the steps which I followed:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

sudo apt-get install docker.io -y
systemctl enable docker.service
systemctl start docker.service

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
lsmod | grep br_netfilter
sudo modprobe br_netfilter

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/modules-load.d/k8s.conf
br_netfilter
EOF

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/k8s.conf
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
EOF
sudo sysctl --system

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
EOF
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker

sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl
sudo curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
sudo hostnamectl set-hostname master-node

kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16

mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
export KUBECONFIG=/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

This can by run within an Ubuntu 20.04 server like a shell script and the Master node will be created.

Tested on **kubeadm version**: 1.23.1
Tested on **kubernetes version**: 1.23.1
**Container Runtime**: Docker

Document reference:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#docker
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are not specify advertiseAddress. I have the same issue and take me couple of hours to find it.