# Kubelet node not found

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubeadm

I'm trying to set up a kubernetes cluster. My `kubeadm init` times out with The `kubelet is unhealthy due to a misconfiguration of the node in some way`. Looking at Kubelet I find that is continuously reporting `Container runtime network not ready`, `Error getting node`, and `Nameserver limits exceeded`.

Looking around for similar problems and I find that existing solutions for similar problems dont work or don't make sense:

1. one candidate is that I'm [missing a pod network addon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58274011/3112506) but that is solved by using `kubectl apply -f` to install the pod network which I cant do because kubectl cant run without a existing cluster (which I cannot create, hence the problem).
2. the other candidate is that I havent [correctly installed docker](https://serverfault.com/a/1088794/404513) for kublet to find it but that doesn't make sense because cri-docker is running and seems to be fine (see below)
3. [Too many entries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59897608/3112506) in my `/etc/resolve.conf` - I checked and I only have one entry.

```
● cri-docker.service - CRI Interface for Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/cri-docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-11-19 17:04:57 UTC; 3h 31min ago
TriggeredBy: ● cri-docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.mirantis.com
   Main PID: 1522 (cri-dockerd)
      Tasks: 30
     Memory: 51.6M
        CPU: 41.468s
     CGroup: /system.slice/cri-docker.service
             └─1522 /usr/local/bin/cri-dockerd --container-runtime-endpoint fd://
```

`sudo journalctl -xeu kubelet` gives me:

```
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
             └─10-kubeadm.conf
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-11-19 19:59:33 UTC; 39min ago
       Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/
   Main PID: 33473 (kubelet)
      Tasks: 36 (limit: 76768)
     Memory: 37.5M
        CPU: 39.709s
     CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
             └─33473 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --container-runtime=remote --container-ru>

Nov 19 20:38:33 master-node kubelet[33473]: E1119 20:38:33.296924   33473 kubelet.go:2448] "Error getting node" err="node \"node\" not found"
...
kubelet.go:2448] "Error getting node" err="node \"node\" not found"
Nov 19 20:38:47 master-node kubelet[33473]: E1119 20:38:47.474190   33473 event.go:276] Unable to write event: '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"node.172914c534e4e80a">
Nov 19 20:38:47 master-node kubelet[33473]: E1119 20:38:47.501529   33473 kubelet.go:2448] "Error getting node" err="node \"node\" not found"
...
kubelet.go:2448] "Error getting node" err="node \"node\" not found"
Nov 19 20:38:50 master-node kubelet[33473]: E1119 20:38:50.044530   33473 kubelet.go:2373] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin>
Nov 19 20:38:50 master-node kubelet[33473]: W1119 20:38:50.075372   33473 reflector.go:424] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: failed to list *v1.RuntimeClass: Get "https://1.2.3.4:6443/apis/node.k8s.io/v1/>
Nov 19 20:38:50 master-node kubelet[33473]: I1119 20:38:50.075518   33473 trace.go:205] Trace[23698761]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134 (19-Nov-2022 20:38:20.073) (total tim>
Nov 19 20:38:50 master-node kubelet[33473]: Trace[23698761]: ---"Objects listed" error:Get "https://1.2.3.4:6443/apis/node.k8s.io/v1/runtimeclasses?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 1.2.3.4:6443: i/o timeout 30001ms >
Nov 19 20:38:50 master-node kubelet[33473]: Trace[23698761]: [30.00168996s] [30.00168996s] END
Nov 19 20:38:50 master-node kubelet[33473]: E1119 20:38:50.075544   33473 reflector.go:140] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:134: Failed to watch *v1.RuntimeClass: failed to list *v1.RuntimeClass: Get "https:/>
Nov 19 20:38:50 master-node kubelet[33473]: E1119 20:38:50.120558   33473 kubelet.go:2448] "Error getting node" err="node \"node\" not found"
...
```

my kube-config.yaml that I pass to `kubeadm init --config kube-config.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
bootstrapTokens:
- groups:
  - system:bootstrappers:kubeadm:default-node-token
  token: abcdef.0123456789abcdef
  ttl: 24h0m0s
  usages:
  - signing
  - authentication
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 1.2.3.4
  bindPort: 6443
nodeRegistration:
  criSocket: unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  name: node
  taints: null
---
apiServer:
  timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
clusterName: kubernetes
controllerManager: {}
dns: {}
etcd:
  local:
    dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
imageRepository: registry.k8s.io
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: 1.25.0
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
scheduler: {}
---
kind: KubeletConfiguration
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
cgroupDriver: systemd
```

What is going wrong here?